# how to make a UDP python localhost go public

Tags: python, udp, public, raspberry-pi, socketserver

I have a python localhost set up on a raspberry pi to listen for UDP packets. But I'm wondering how I can make this a public server in order to send UDP packets from roaming devices.

The below code works perfectly sending UDP packets from a device on the same wireless network.

```
import SocketServer

PORTNO = 14

class handler(SocketServer.DatagramRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        newmsg = self.rfile.readline().rstrip()
    print (newmsg)
        self.wfile.write(self.server.oldmsg)
        self.server.oldmsg = newmsg

s = SocketServer.UDPServer(('',PORTNO), handler)
print "Awaiting UDP messages on port %d" % PORTNO
s.oldmsg = "This is the starting message."
s.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a networking issue. You will have to configure your router with appropriate [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). If your ISP does not have static IP's you may also need to set-up some [dynamic DNS](http://dyn.com/dns/) service.

The NAT traversal required to connect to external networks requires a static IP outside the 192.168.*.* or 10.*.*.* range. This is typically assigned by the ISP DHCP server to the external facing MAC Address of the router.

The port forward settings are shown here:
[image: D_Link port forward]

Comment: can port forwarding be done from the raspberry pi? I've set the raspberry pi to have a static ip already

Comment: I can provide more detailed notes on NAT traversal and Port forwarding if we know the model of your router. Note that opening ports to the outside can be a security risk.

Comment: that would be great. it is a D-link dir-615.